# Trying to cross-check two ranges in Google Sheets with a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I am currently trying to write a script to compare two ranges in Google Sheets. One is a list of emails to contact in (sht1), and the other is a list of emails on a blacklist in (sht2). I want to automate a script that will compare each email in the contact list in sht1, with ALL of the emails in the blacklist of sht2. If the value in sht1 at point [i] matches any of the values in the blacklist in sht2[j], from sht2[0] to sht2[length] it will automatically cause the row in sht1 to delete at [i].

However, the script is not working. I keep getting the error "range out of bounds" I have tried changing the conditions of i from if(var i=0;i

Any help would be great appreciated.

```
function DeleteDupes()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht1=ss.getSheetByName('Email List All');
  var dd = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('noneofyourbusiness')
  var sht2=dd.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rng1=sht1.getRange('A:A');
  var rng2=sht2.getRange('A:A');
  var rng1A=rng1.getValues();
  var rng2A=rng2.getValues();
  for(var i=rng1A.length;i>=0;i--)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<=rng2A.length;j++)
    {
      if(rng1A[i]==rng2A[j]);
      sht1.deleteRow(i-1);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function DeleteDupes(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht1=ss.getSheetByName('Email List All');
  var dd = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('noneofyourbusiness')
  var sht2=dd.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rng1=sht1.getRange('A:A');
  var rng2=sht2.getRange('A:A');

  // Code changes begin here:
  var rng1A=formatRangeValues(rng1);
  var rng2A=formatRangeValues(rng2);

  // Keep only the emails in `rng1A` that are not in `rng2A`
  var filteredEmails = rng1A.filter(function(email){
    return this.indexOf(email) === -1;
  }, rng2A);

  // Remove all emails in `rng1` in preparation of inserting filtered list
  rng1.clearContent();

  // Protect against an empty `filteredEmails` array
  if(filteredEmails.length === 0) 
    return;

  // Convert `filteredEmails` back to a 2D Range 
  // and insert back into Column A
  sht1
    .getRange(1, 1, filteredEmails.length)
    .setValues(
      filteredEmails.map(function(e){ 
        return [e] ;
      })
    );
}

// Filter out blank elements. 
// reduce{concat} flattens the array
function formatRangeValues(range){
  return range
    .getValues()
    .filter(String)
    .reduce(function(a,b){ 
       return a.concat(b) 
    }, []);
}
```

This will remove any instances of an email on sht1 that are on sht2.  It works by bringing the sht1 Range into memory and converting it to an array of values.  It then filters the values and inserts them back into sht1.

There are two major advantages of doing the data manipulation in JavaScript instead of on the spreadsheet. First, it is going to be faster.  Reads and writes to the spreadsheet document are expensive.  This way we can batch them instead of doing them individually.  Second, it is safer as it only manipulates the cells in question.  We do not need to worry about side effects (such as deleting a row when other columns may someday be used).

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much for giving me the breakdown. I had no idea about these rules, or how to use the indexof function before this. Your explanation is super helpful. Thank you again!!

Comment: @Devin So glad that this was not only solve your problem, but also expand your knowledge as well!  Can you accept the answer to make it easier for future visitors to find and learn from as well?

Answer (score 0):

## Deleting Items on a BlackList

Try this:

```
function delItemsOnBlacklist() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Contacts');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('BlackList')
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),1);
  var rg2=sh2.getRange(1,1,sh2.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var vB=rg2.getValues();
  var vBlackList=[];
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vB.length;i++){
    vBlackList.push(vB[i][0]);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    if(vBlackList.indexOf(vA[i][0])>-1){
      sh1.deleteRow(i-d+1);
      d++;
    }
  }
}
```

I changed your file names and range descriptions a bit so make sure you make the appropriate changes.  I prefer to put the blacklist into an array.  It just seems neater to me. If you keep track of the deleted items as in "d" and add that to the deleteRow then you can increment in the loop which I think were more use to doing.

Comment: When I first posted it I had `sh1.deleteRow(i+d+1);` and it should be `sh1.deleteRow(i-d+1);`